# if then statement in php function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a PHP beginner. I have trouble to making a basic if/then statement on function.

I add a woocommerce product tab 'Food_paring', I want to disable the tab when the field 'food_pairing" is empty/not set.

original code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'new_product_tab' );

function new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    /* Adds the new tab */
    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Food Pairing', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,  
        'callback'  => 'food_pairing_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;  /* Return all  tabs including the new New Custom Product Tab  to display */
}

function food_pairing_tab_content() {
    /* The new tab content */
    echo '<h2>Food Pairing</h2><p id="tab-food-pairing">', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'food_pairing', true ), '</p>';
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the field/variable 'food_pairing' that you want to test in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code. Before add tab check if product meta has value or not `global $post; if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'food_pairing', true )){..}`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'new_product_tab' );

function new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $post;
    /* Adds the new tab */
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'food_pairing', true ))
    {
        $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
            'title'     => __( 'Food Pairing', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority'  => 50,  
            'callback'  => 'food_pairing_tab_content'
        );
    }
    return $tabs;  /* Return all  tabs including the new New Custom Product Tab  to display */
}

function food_pairing_tab_content() {
    /* The new tab content */
    echo '<h2>Food Pairing</h2><p id="tab-food-pairing">', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'food_pairing', true ), '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) { 
   global $woocommerce;
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array( 
        'title' => __( 'Ingredients', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'priority' => 50, 
        'callback' => 'woo_new_product_tab_content' ,
     ); 
    return $tabs;
 }
function woo_new_product_tab_content() { 
        // The new tab content
          echo '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>'; 
        echo $prod_id = get_the_ID();
        echo'<p>'.get_post_meta($prod_id,'ingredients',true).'</p>';
}
```

this code is properly working... should try . Good Luck